# Firebase File Download

Tags: java, android, firebase

I upload the file correctly, now I want to download, there are no errors but logcat says the download was done but I can not find the file in the phone memory
And other version this code generate an error

CODE:

```
 public void download(){
    try{
        //DatabaseReference databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    //StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl(url);

    final StorageReference storageRef = storage
            .getReferenceFromUrl("gs://the-piraty-book-alpha1.appspot.com/arquivos/")
            .child(nome);

        File storagePath = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"TPB");
        if(!storagePath.exists()) {
            storagePath.mkdirs();
        }

        File localFile = null;
        localFile = File.createTempFile("arquivo","pdf");

        final File finalLocalFile = localFile;
        FileDownloadTask task = storageRef.getFile(localFile);
        task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Log.e("firebase ",";local tem file created  created " + finalLocalFile.toString());

            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                Log.e("firebase ",";local tem file not created  created " +exception.toString());
            }
        });

    }catch (IOException e){

    }
}
```

`10-01 13:35:51.118 31218-31218/ktm.com.menu E/firebase: ;local tem file created  created /data/user/0/ktm.com.menu/cache/arquivo572065630pdf`

not founding in my phone
,my manifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />
```

Comment: If there is an error, please add the exact and complete stack trace to your question.

Comment: not error, 
10-01 14:08:08.673 31218-31218/ktm.com.menu E/firebase: ;local tem file created  created /data/user/0/ktm.com.menu/cache/arquivo1980466363pdf
10-01 14:10:34.480 31218-31218/ktm.com.menu E/firebase: ;local tem file created  created /data/user/0/ktm.com.menu/cache/arquivo79456782pdf

Comment: It says that is created. If you are going to that location, the file isn't there?

Comment: this location does not exist on my phone, I try to search but I can not find it, the cache makes me think that it does not download it as a pdf, since the standard android download notification does not appear ... I can not solve it, error to look for a solution

Comment: Are you getting any excetions?

Comment: none, :( nothing